# Note next to node

Tags: forest

I'm trying to add a few notes next to each node to forest in `LaTeX`, but I do not know how to do it.

Does anyone know how we can add this color combination in Rectangle next to the node in forest?

[image: the first picture is how the tree looks like]
[image: the second is how it looks after adding the notes.]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{forest} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    grow=south,
    top color = white,
    bottom color = white,
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=12ex,
    inner sep=7pt,
    s sep=15mm,
}
[{\{a,b,c,d\}}
    [{\{a,b,c,d\}}
        [{\{a,d,c\}}
            [{\{d,c\}}
                [{\{c\}}
                    [{\{g,c\}}
                        [{\{g\}}]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [{\{a,b,c,d\}}
        [{\{a,b,c,d\}}
            [{\{b,d,c\}}
                [{\{b,c\}}
                    [{\{b\}}
                        [{\{b,e\}}
                            [{\{e\}}]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [{\{a,b,c,d\}}
        [{\{a,b,c\}}
            [{\{ac\}}
                [{\{a\}}
                    [{\{a,f\}}
                        [{\{f\}}]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A classic label should do. Forest should handle this properly, so `label={[draw, rounded corners, align=left]right:<text>}` where `<text>` is the actual content. You will need some fine adjustments here and there but that should be a start.

Comment: As @Qrrbrbirlbel says, `label` is the simplest option. You will probably need to increase `s sep` to avoid overlapping nodes. `forest` won't take account of the space the labels take because they're drawn too late.

Comment: Please can you complete your code fragment so it compiles?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel It works, but the Rectangle is very close to the node. Do you know how to add space between them?

Comment: The key [`/tikz/label distance`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/label:distance) can be used but you can always move the label by using `xshift`, `yshift` and `shift`.